# Tamaño del fichero final de Wikidata

Tags: json, linux, zip

estoy intentando descomprimir el dump más reciente de Wikidata para un proyecto, el problema es que o no tengo espacio suficiente en disco o la copia que he descargado se ha corrompido (el dump pesa 56Gb). Trato de ver cuanto ocupa usando

```
gzip -l lattest-all.json.gz
```

sin embargo el output dice que es *3*, con una tasa de compresión negativa.

Espero que alguien pueda decirme cuanto pesa el fichero final. Gracias a todos, un saludo.

Comment: Pon el output completo que lo veamos, porque con esa opción `-l` deberías de poder ver la siguiente información en orden: Tamaño comprimido, tamaño descomprimido, ratio y nombre del archivo comprimido que hay dentro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapidez en la respuesta, me lo volví a descargar por si estaba corrupto el archivo pero me da exactamente el mismo output que la vez anterior  ```59084138294                   3 -1969471275766.7% latest-all.json```

Answer (score 0):

Con este comando puedes ver el peso expresado en bytes:

```
gzip -dc file.gz |wc -c
```

Hice una prueba con un archivo ISO y me dió un valor de "696539136", que serían unos 696 MB.

Saludos!

Comment: Al ejecutarlo dice
```tar: Esto no parece un archivo tar
tar: Saltando a la siguiente cabecera```, así que seguiré investigando. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Al probarlo solo muestra eso por pantalla, después no devuelve nada...

Comment: Acabo de probar con "gzip -dc file.gz | wc -c" y me da el resultado en bytes, algo como "696539136", que serían unos 696 MB, puedes probarlo ?

Comment: Buenas, despues de lanzar el comando me devuelve 793949503250, según la conversión que comentas sería en torno a 793GB si no me salen mal las cuentas... Podría ser eso, que me falte sitio. ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Genial Antonio! Saludos!